# Can't calculate % of row in Excel Pivot Table

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2013, pivot-table

Product types A, B, C, D
Each type has numerous products, say type A has 100 products, type B 50 etc..

```
product#    product type     buyer
01          A                john
02          A                
...
101         B                mary
102         B                peter
...
```

I want to calculate % of products sold per product type. My pivot table looks like:

```
total = count(product#)  ' number of 'product#' column 
sold = count(buyer)      ' number of non-empty 'buyer' column

product type    total    sold     %sold
A               100      50       50%
B               50       20       40%
```

I can get pivot table to show "total" and "sold" columns, but how do I calculate "%sold" column?

Comment: Your question isn't clear now. How can you get total and sold amount of products from your original data?

Comment: Added 'buyer' column where an empty cell means it's not sold.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a new column where you put `1` for sold and `0` for the other rows.
(can do easily with a formula: `=(C2<>"")*1`)

Then in table pivot table just calculate average of this column and format it as percentage.

[image]